# when i make a stripe payment then i get internal server error

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, react-stripe

```
when i make a stripe payment then i get internal server error
stipe version is 12.9.0,
```

this my backend code

```
    const ErrorHander = require("../utils/errorhander");
        const cachasycError = require("../middleware/cachasycError");
        const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
        //prosees payment
        exports.paymentProcess = cachasycError(async (req, res, next) => {
          const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: req.body.amount,
            currency: "usd",
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            metadata: {
              company: "Ecommerce",
            },
          });
        
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          });
        });
        
        //sent public key
        exports.publicstripeapikey = cachasycError(async (req, res, next) => {
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            stripeapikey: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY,
          });
        });
```

this my frontend code

```
    const ErrorHander = require("../utils/errorhander");
        const cachasycError = require("../middleware/cachasycError");
        const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
        //prosees payment
        exports.paymentProcess = cachasycError(async (req, res, next) => {
          const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: req.body.amount,
            currency: "usd",
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            metadata: {
              company: "Ecommerce",
            },
          });
        
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          });
        });
        
        //sent public key
        exports.publicstripeapikey = cachasycError(async (req, res, next) => {
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            stripeapikey: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY,
          });
        });
    
    
    
   this is my fond end code
    import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import CheckoutSteps from "../cart/CheckoutSteps";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import MetaData from "../layout/Header/Metadata";
    import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
    import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
    
    import {
      CardNumberElement,
      CardCvcElement,
      CardExpiryElement,
      useStripe,
      useElements,
    } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
    
    import axios from "axios";
    import "./payment.css";
    import CreditCardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CreditCard";
    import EventIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Event";
    import VpnKeyIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VpnKey";
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    // import { createOrder, clearErrors } from "../../actions/orderAction";
    
    const Payment = () => {
      const history = useNavigate();
    
      const orderInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("orderInfo"));
    
      // const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const stripe = useStripe();
      const elements = useElements();
      const payBtn = useRef(null);
    
      const { shippingInfo, cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
      const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
      // const { error } = useSelector((state) => state.newOrder);
    
      const paymentData = {
        amount: Math.round(orderInfo.totalPrice * 100),
      };
    
      const order = {
        shippingInfo,
        orderItems: cartItems,
        itemsPrice: orderInfo.subtotal,
        taxPrice: orderInfo.tax,
        shippingPrice: orderInfo.shippingCharges,
        totalPrice: orderInfo.totalPrice,
      };
    
      const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        payBtn.current.disabled = true;
    
        try {
          const config = {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          };
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            "/api/v1/payment/process",
            paymentData,
            config
          );
    
          const client_secret = data.client_secret;
    
          if (!stripe || !elements) return;
    
          const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
            payment_method: {
              card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
              billing_details: {
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                address: {
                  line1: shippingInfo.address,
                  city: shippingInfo.city,
                  state: shippingInfo.state,
                  postal_code: shippingInfo.pinCode,
                  country: shippingInfo.country,
                },
              },
            },
          });
    
          if (result.error) {
            payBtn.current.disabled = false;
            toast(result.error.message);
          } else {
            if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
              order.paymentInfo = {
                id: result.paymentIntent.id,
                status: result.paymentIntent.status,
              };
              console.log("order");
              console.log(order);
              //   dispatch(createOrder(order));
    
              history("/success");
            } else {
              alert.error("There's some issue while processing payment ");
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          payBtn.current.disabled = false;
          // alert.error(error.response.data.message);
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // if (error) {
        //   alert.error(error);
        //   dispatch(clearErrors());
        // }
      }, [alert]);
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <ToastContainer />
          <MetaData title="Payment" />
          <CheckoutSteps activeStep={2} />
          <div className="paymentContainer">
            <form className="paymentForm" onSubmit={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>
              <Typography>Card Info</Typography>
              <div>
                <CreditCardIcon />
                <CardNumberElement className="paymentInput" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <EventIcon />
                <CardExpiryElement className="paymentInput" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <VpnKeyIcon />
                <CardCvcElement className="paymentInput" />
              </div>
    
              <input
                type="submit"
                value={`Pay - ₹${orderInfo && orderInfo.totalPrice}`}
                ref={payBtn}
                className="paymentFormBtn"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default Payment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro i got the same error it client_secret is undefined

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.